# How do I hide dotfiles only in the home directory in dired buffers?

Tags: dired, directory-local-variables, dired-omit-mode

I would like to hide dotfiles only in the home directory in dired buffers, but I do not know how to achieve this. I have been trying with the following:

```
(use-package dired
  :ensure nil
  :commands (dired dired-jump)
  :bind (("C-x C-j" . dired-jump)
         (:map dired-mode-map ("C-c h" . dired-omit-mode)))
  :config
  (setq dired-omit-files (rx (seq bol "."))) ; hide dotfiles in dired-omit-mode

  (defun najjt/dired-after-readin ()
    "Turn on dired-omit-mode if current buffer is a dired buffer in the home directory."
    (if (string-equal (buffer-name) "najjt") ; check if current buffer name is equal to name of home dir
        (dired-omit-mode 1)
      (dired-omit-mode nil)))

  :hook ((dired-after-readin . (lambda () (najjt/dired-after-readin))))
  )
```

But it seems to hide dotfiles in all directories, not just my home directory.

Comment: `.dir-locals.el` may help

Answer (score 3):

Instead of bothering with using `dired-omit-mode` to hide dot files, just use the `ls` switches that give you that behavior (pretty much anything other than switch `-a`).

And do that only in a particular directory (e.g., your home directory) by using a `.dir-locals-file` that specifies the specific value of `dired-listing-switches` that gives you the behavior you want.

(`.dir-locals-file` is the default value of variable `dir-locals-file`. See [(elisp) Directory Local Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Directory-Local-Variables.html).)

Comment: So, I have created a file called `.dir-locals.el` in my home directory, which contains this: `((dired-mode . ((dired-listing-switches . "-lh"))))`. I am not sure this is correct, however, because it does not hide anything.